# Open With - Change All reverts back to original application CS5/CC

Tags: macos, mac

I have just set up a Mac (10.8.4) with CS5 and CC.

By default all my Indesign files now want to open in Indesign Creative Cloud. If I Get Info of the file and choose Indesign CS5 and then select Change All, the selected app reverts back to Indesign CC.

If I don't choose Change All and just modify the one Indesign document the setting sticks. However I need to change all my Indesign/Photoshop files to open in the CS5 app.

I have tried rebuilding the launch services. But the default application still reverts to CC whenever I hit Change All.

Any ideas?

Comment: You could try changing the default application with [duti](http://duti.org) or [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) instead of Finder, but it probably won't help.

Comment: I am having the same problem as well.. As far as I can tell from some other forums.. people have been having the problem since 2009... :S Their only suggestion is to use a terminal prompt, but even that doesn't work 50% of the time.. So it is still a problem for most :(

Comment: When you say you're having the same problem, is this specific to Creative Suite versions? Or are you seeing this across many different applications?

Comment: I have the same problem, in 2016 in OSX Yosemite 10.10.5

Answer (score 1):

It's expected behaviour.

There is only one creator type shared by both versions, so the system will always choose the newest version.
You can probably see it better if you try to change it using [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/). It will only offer the newest installed version of valid apps in the drop-menu for any file type.

[image]